# How to include an object with saved text in expression() to be used in ggplot2 graph?

Tags: r, ggplot2, expression

I'm trying to combine mathematical symbols and objects with values saved to them to be displayed in a ggplot graph with geom_text(). Here's example code related to my problem:

```
# values 
diff <- "0.81"
p <- "p < .01"

# approach 1) pasting in values
temp <- data.frame(condition = c("first"), value = c(2)) %>%
  mutate(test = as.character(expression(atop(beta["2"] - beta["1"] == "-0.80", "p < 0.01")))) 

ggplot() +
      geom_bar(data = temp, aes(x = condition, y = value), stat = "identity") +
      ylim(0, 5) +
      geom_text(data = temp, x = 1, y = 4, aes(label = test), size = 7, parse = TRUE) 

# approach 2) referring to objects with values
temp <- data.frame(condition = c("first"), value = c(2)) %>%
  mutate(test = as.character(expression(atop(beta["2"] - beta["1"] == diff, p))))

ggplot() +
  geom_bar(data = temp, aes(x = condition, y = value), stat = "identity") +
  ylim(0, 5) +
  geom_text(data = temp, x = 1, y = 4, aes(label = test), size = 7, parse = TRUE)
```

Approach 1 creates the graph I'm aiming for, but I want to be able to easily refer to objects to supply values to appear following the betas. If I take the current approach 2, it doesn't use the values saved to the objects, but instead just the text "diff" and "p". Is there a way to maintain the basic structure of approach 1 but using objects to create the graph I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what you want to happen when you have more rows, but if you want to partially exapnd some variables, i think that's easiest to do with `bquote`. I pulled it out into a function because to get it to properly vectorize can be a bit tricky

```
mylabs <- function(diff, p) {
  sapply(mapply(function(diff, p) bquote(atop(beta["2"] - beta["1"] == .(diff), .(p))), diff, p), deparse)
}

temp <- data.frame(condition = c("first"), value = c(2)) %>%
  mutate(test = mylabs(diff, p))
```